# besside-ng "bad beacon" error when attempting to deauth (aircrack-ng)

Tags: wifi, sniffing, aircrack-ng, airodump-ng

Equipment: Alfa AWUS036ACH Wi-Fi adapter AC1200
Fresh Install of Kali Linux, fully updated (not on a VM)

I have been running across this same "bad beacon" error (sometimes with "DEAUTH" in front of it) when trying to run besside-ng.  I am running besside-ng after I run the `sudo airmon-ng start wlan1` command, which I get the message stating that I should run the `airmon-ng check kill`, which I do.  Resulting in:

Killing these processes:

```
PID Name
615 wpa_supplicant
```

Then I'm running: `sudo airodump-ng wlan1`, which gives me plenty of network data for all access points, with BSSIDs, channels etc. I capture the BSSID and enter it in the "X's" below.

But when I run `sudo besside-ng -b XX:XX:XX:XX:XX:XX wlan1`, it gives me the bad beacon errors below.  So I thought maybe I needed to turn back on my network manager (as before it had been being closed with the check kill command above, even though it wasn't in my example this time) and I still can't get besside-ng to handshake.

Has anyone seen this before?

```
sudo besside-ng -b XX:XX:XX:XX:XX:XX wlan1
[18:18:07] Let's ride
[18:18:07] Autodetecting supported channels...
[18:18:07] Resuming from besside.log
[18:18:07] Appending to wpa.cap
[18:18:07] Appending to wep.cap
[18:18:07] Logging to besside.log
[18:18:08] | Scanning chan 02
Bad beacon
[18:18:09] / Scanning chan 05
Bad beacon
[18:18:09] - Scanning chan 06
Bad beacon
[18:18:09] \ Scanning chan 06
Bad beacon
[18:18:10] | Scanning chan 06
Bad beacon
[18:18:10] / Scanning chan 06
Bad beacon
[18:18:10] \ Scanning chan 06
Bad beacon
[18:18:10] | Scanning chan 06
Bad beacon
[18:18:10] / Scanning chan 06
Bad beacon
[18:18:10] - Scanning chan 06
Bad beacon
[18:18:10] | Scanning chan 06
Bad beacon
[18:18:10] / Scanning chan 06
Bad beacon
[18:18:10] - Scanning chan 06
Bad beacon
[18:18:10] - Scanning chan 06
Bad beacon
[18:18:10] | Scanning chan 06
Bad beacon
[18:18:10] / Scanning chan 06
Bad beacon
[18:18:10] - Scanning chan 06
Bad beacon
[18:18:10] \ Scanning chan 07
Bad beacon
[18:18:10] | Scanning chan 07
Bad beacon
[18:18:10] / Scanning chan 07
Bad beacon
[18:18:10] - Scanning chan 07
Bad beacon
[18:18:10] | Scanning chan 08
Bad beacon
[18:18:10] / Scanning chan 08
Bad beacon
[18:18:10] - Scanning chan 08
Bad beacon
[18:18:10] \ Scanning chan 08
Bad beacon
[18:18:11] - Scanning chan 10
Bad beacon
[18:18:11] / Scanning chan 11
Bad beacon
[18:18:11] - Scanning chan 11
Bad beacon
[18:18:11] | Scanning chan 11
Bad beacon
[18:18:11] / Scanning chan 11
Bad beacon
[18:18:11] - Scanning chan 11
Bad beacon
```